# Accessing IMS DB with SQL calls from IBM Data studio client

Tags: sql, jdbc, ims-db

I am trying to set up SQL call to IMS DB using imsudb.jar in IBM Data studio client, but got stuck with below issues can some one help me out

1. How can I get my IMS DB URL and port details without DBA contact?
2. How do I export the DBD, PCB and create metadata for it the relational
   DB model?

Answer (score 1):

In response to your questions:

**1. How can I get my IMS DB URL and port details without DBA contact?**

The IMS DB url and port are based on the IMS Connect settings that your system programmer (not a DBA) would of set up.

If you have terminal access to your IMS system, then you would use the same hostname/ipaddress that you used to connect to the terminal. Assuming that IMS Connect is up and running, you can query it to discover what the data ports are with the following command: nnVIEWPORT ALL

The ports for data access will be listed with D (e.g., 5555D indicates port 5555 is used for data)

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPH2_15.1.0/com.ibm.ims15.doc.cr/compcmds/ims_viewport.htm

**2. How do I export the DBD, PCB and create metadata for it the relational DB model?**

You will want to use the IMS Explorer for Development to generate the metadata for your database. It generates several metadata artifacts depending on whether you are using the IMS catalog or a local copy of metadata.

https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/ims-enterprise-suite/details#product-header-top